# How to retrieve the current element with addEventListener based on class?

Tags: javascript, html, events, dom-events

I am using a function to retrieve the current element that receives an event (a click in this case), but I'd like to remove the function from my HTML script and use an `event listener` to do the same, however I am using a class to aim the elements. If I had only one element it would be easy, but that's not the case.

My first thought was to use `querySelector`, but it gives me only the first element, as it should be.
I could use `querySelectorAll`, but in that case I believe I would need an `index` or something like that, what implies a loop and, therefore, a function inside the HTML script, which is exactly what I am trying to avoid in this scenery.

In short, if I click on the first element I want to retrieve it, if I click on the second I want the second and so on, but I'd like to do that within the same `event listener`.

Is there a simple way to do that?

P.S. I don't want to use IDs.

```js
//This is what I'm doing:
function getElement() {
  const element = event.currentTarget
  
  console.log(element)
}

//This is what I want to do:
/*
const elements = document.querySelector('.class-example')

elements.addEventListener('click', (e) => console.log(e.currentTarget))
*/
```

```css
.class-example {
  cursor: pointer;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}

.class-example:first-of-type {
  background-color: red;
}

.class-example:nth-of-type(2) {
  background-color: yellow;
}

.class-example:nth-of-type(3) {
  background-color: green;
}

.class-example:nth-of-type(4) {
  background-color: blue;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<div onClick="getElement()" class="class-example" >Div 1</div>
<div onClick="getElement()" class="class-example" >Div 2</div>
<div onClick="getElement()" class="class-example" >Div 3</div>
<div onClick="getElement()" class="class-example" >Div 4</div>
```

Comment: Afaik, you cannot put an event listener on multiple elements at once unless you loop over them and attach one on each element. You can however simply put an event listener on the whole document and then only match what you need: `document.addEventListener('click',function(e){ if(e.target && e.target.classList.contains('class-example')){ //do something } });`

Comment: Side note: This has the added benefit that it'll work for dynamically added element as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two possible approaches ...

... one either does subscribe each element to the event one does wish to be notified about and wants to handle ...

```js
function getExampleNode(evt) {
  const elmNode = evt.currentTarget;
 
  console.log(elmNode);

  return elmNode;
}

function mainInit() {
  document
    .querySelectorAll('.class-example')
    .forEach(elmNode =>
      elmNode.addEventListener('click', getExampleNode)
    );
}
mainInit();
```

```css
.class-example {
  cursor: pointer;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
}
.class-example:first-of-type {
  background-color: red;
}
.class-example:nth-of-type(2) {
  background-color: yellow;
}
.class-example:nth-of-type(3) {
  background-color: green;
}
.class-example:nth-of-type(4) {
  background-color: blue;
  color: white;
}

.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 50%!important; }
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="A class-example">
    <span>within ...
      <span>div 1</span>
    </span>
  </div>
  <div class="B class-example">
    <span>within ...
      <span>div 2</span>
    </span>
  </div>
  <div class="C class-example">
    <span>within ...
      <span>div 3</span>
    </span>
  </div>
  <div class="D class-example">
    <span>within ...
      <span>div 4</span>
    </span>
  </div>
</div>
```

... or one makes use of event delegation where one does subscribe just a single grouping element to this very event.

```js
function getExampleNode(evt) {
  const containerNode = evt.currentTarget;
  const targetNode = evt.target; // either <span/> or <div/>

  let exampleNode;
  let isInExample;

  Array.from(
    document.querySelectorAll('.class-example')
  ).some(elmNode => {
    isInExample = (elmNode === targetNode) || elmNode.contains(targetNode);
    if (isInExample) {

      exampleNode = elmNode;
    }
    return isInExample;
  });

  console.log('targetNode :', targetNode);
  console.log('exampleNode :', exampleNode);
  console.log('\n');

  return exampleNode;
}

function mainInit() {
  document
    .querySelector('.container')
    .addEventListener('click', getExampleNode);
}
mainInit();
```

```css
.class-example {
  cursor: pointer;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
}
.class-example:first-of-type {
  background-color: red;
}
.class-example:nth-of-type(2) {
  background-color: yellow;
}
.class-example:nth-of-type(3) {
  background-color: green;
}
.class-example:nth-of-type(4) {
  background-color: blue;
  color: white;
}

.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 50%!important; }
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="A class-example">
    <span>within ...
      <span>div 1</span>
    </span>
  </div>
  <div class="B class-example">
    <span>within ...
      <span>div 2</span>
    </span>
  </div>
  <div class="C class-example">
    <span>within ...
      <span>div 3</span>
    </span>
  </div>
  <div class="D class-example">
    <span>within ...
      <span>div 4</span>
    </span>
  </div>
</div>
```

The first approach's advantage is its simple event handling for one always can be sure about the event's `currentTarget` which equals one of the elements one was subscribing to the very event.

The disadvantage comes less from the amount of event listeners one did create in first place, but more from the possible loss of handling information in case one has to deal with elements which are added later to the DOM.

The latter scenario gets covered by the second approach. The event registration here is much simpler, but the implementation of the event handler is a little bit more complex.

One has to provide additional logic which searches for the desired element by figuring out wich of the possible elements does contain or equal the event's `currentTarget`.

Comment: I like the first option better. I was going for the event delegation, but I would have to make some verifications, since I have several nested elements. The first possibility gives me a straight response. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 3):

Afaik, it's not possible to put an event listener on multiple elements at once unless you loop over them and attach one on each element. You can however simply put an event listener on the whole document and then only match what you need:

```
document.addEventListener('click',function(e){
    if(e.target && e.target.classList.contains('class-example')){
        //do something
    }
});
```

This has the added benefit that it'll work for dynamically added elements as well.

Edit (thanks to Mitya): This is known as event delegation. If you're interested in more information about this, [Mitya](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1352288/mitya) provides a guide [here](https://mitya.uk/articles/javascript-event-delegation).

Comment: This is called event delegation. If the OP wishes to research this more, I have a [guide to it here](https://mitya.uk/articles/javascript-event-delegation).

Comment: I can work with that. Thank you very much.

Comment: @Berg_Durden ... I do not advice this approach for it only works in case the searched/desired element does not contain any other element(s) itself. Every generic approach takes this very common use case into account. Please have a look at the provided answer of mine.